# In JSP, how to escape a string value for JavaScript first, then for HTML?

Tags: spring, jsp, escaping, xss

In a project using JSP and Spring, what would be the simplest way to escape an EL expression value for JavaScript first, then for HTML?

Imagine this use:

```
<a onclick='alert("${note}");'>Foo</a>
```

This is susceptible to XSS or plain syntax errors, as the variable value can contain *quote*, *less-than* and other characters.

What I came up is:

```
<a onclick='alert("<c:out value="${null}"
><s:escapeBody htmlEscape="false" javaScriptEscape="true"
>${variable}</s:escapeBody></c:out>");'>Foo</a>
<!-- this escapes first the inner tags body for JS,
     then c:out uses that (because its value attribute
     is null, it uses what is in its own body) and
     escapes it for HTML/XML -->
```

It is rather clumsy, so I'm looking for a more elegant way.

(note that using just `<s:escapeBody htmlEscape="true" javaScriptEscape="true">` is incorrect as the tag escapes first for HTML and then for JS, so for example it would fail on the value of `a"b`)

Comment: @BalusC the supposed duplicate asks about escaping JS, here the question is about HTML and JS. The answer there could be used as _part_ of an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting clumsy code, I would suggest you create a small custom taglib which provides a function exactly for that. You can implement that very easily by using [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) in commons-lang.

Then you can write:

```
<a onclick='alert("${foo:escapeJsHtml(note)}");'>Foo</a>
```

Comment: The _StringEscapeUtils_ method _escapeHtml3_ (or 4) would fail spectacularly here, as it does not escape the apostrophe character.

Comment: But escapeEcmaScript does.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)

Comment: Irrelevant. The result would be: `<a onclick='alert("abc\' this here is not part of the onclick attribute any more as its value was terminated by the apostrophe")'>...`.  But using a proper HTML escape method (like Spring [HtmlUtils.htmlEscape](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape-java.lang.String-)) would make your solution work.

Comment: ok; then it should be enough to write `<a onclick="alert('${fn:escapeXml(note)}">...</a>` to avoid the `<c:out />' ugliness, right?